# Cannot parse the output of a C function into R

Tags: c, r, r-package

I'm hacking third-party R code (and the C code in `/src`) which makes queries to a database. The way the R package does this is to use `.C()` to interact with C code.

(Note: my understanding is that `.C()` is deprecated and users are recommended to use `.Call()` instead).

```
foobar = .C('query_row', file, index, query)
```

This actually does work in R when the R function is called. However, foobar is of type `list`, and calling `.C()` simply prints the C output into the R terminal:

```
> foobar = .C('query_row', file, index, query)
## outputs the query from the C function 'query_row'`
row1    row2    row3   row4 
row1    row2    row3   row4 
row1    row2    row3   row4 
row1    row2    row3   row4 
...
> foobar       ### now, I cannot access the output from the C function
[[1]]
[1] "/path/dbfile"

[[2]]
[1] "/path/dbindex"

[[3]]
[1] "query_string"
```

I actually cannot work with the output of the C function, even though it prints to the R terminal. How could I "grab" this C output so I could put it into an R data structure? Something like `fread()` from `data.table` or `paste()` from base R

I first thought I could use `readLines()` as if this was a connection:

```
> readLines(.C('query_row', file, index, query))
## outputs the query from the C function 'query_row'`
row1    row2    row3   row4 
row1    row2    row3   row4 
row1    row2    row3   row4 
row1    row2    row3   row4 
...
Error in readLines(.C('query_row', file, : 
      'con' is not a connection
```

It still outputs the C output into the R terminal, but throws an error at `readLines()`

I've tried re-writing this with `.Call()`, but I get a massive error:

```
*** caught segfault ***
address 0x20000090, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: .Call(.C('query_row', file, index, query, package = 'packageName'))

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
```

EDIT: Here is the `query_row` C source code. It looks like it's just printing to STDOUT:

```
void
query_row(char **input, char **dbfile, char **query)
{
    db_row_set_t *row_set = get_query_rows(*input_file_name, *dbfile, *query);

    if (row_set != NULL) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < row_set->n_entries; ++j) {
            print_db_row(row_set->rows[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

and `print_db_row` is just a wrapper around `printf()`

```
void
print_db_row(db_row_set_t *row)
{
    printf("%s", row->row1name);
    printf("\t%s", row->row2name);
    printf("\t%s", row->row3name);
    printf("\t%s", row->row4name);
}
```

Comment: If you could show the `query_row` source I could probably give you an answer. When using `.C()` in the past, I would have typically passed a pre-initialized (named) argument that was supposed to be filled with the output from within the executed C code.

Comment: @RolandASc I've added the function above. It looks like it's just printing to STDOUT. Let me know if the above doesn't make sense.

Comment: ok - I think you would add a `char **result` to the `void query_row(...)`, extend your call to `.C('query_row', ..., result = character(4)`, and then do e.g. `strcat` in addition to printing in `print_db_row` and return the resulting char array into the corresponding element of `result`. Afterwards you can access the result under `foobar$result`. I should still point out that for character vector output or more advanced the .C() interface is not really recommended. My personal preference would be to use `Rcpp` as the interface here.

Comment: @RolandASc  Thanks for the help! " My personal preference would be to use Rcpp as the interface here." I would love to do this, but I've never understood how it should work with C code.

Comment: @RolandASc "return the resulting char array into the corresponding element of result" I seem to run into bugs here. Could you be a bit more concrete? `strcat()` an empty `char **` and `print_db_row()`?